# SOAP Webservice Automation Testing

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui, postman

**Consider:**
There exists SOAP webservices (in XMLs).
Some SOAP Services are dependent on other SOAP services.
For example, Consider there are 2 webservices SOAP1 and SOAP2.
The value retrieved in the response XML of SOAP1 will be the input value in the request XML of SOAP2.

**Objective:**
Automate the testing of these SOAP webservices.

**Question:**
How can we automate the soap webservices as mentioned in the **Consider** section? Any links?
(We can use PostMan or SOAP UI Open source version.)
Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Selenium is for web UI testing...

Comment: if not Selenium, Please suggest any other process by which we can test the SOAP services as mentioned in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer in the below link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSAt7YOvjbY

The name of the feature that helps us transferring 1 value from 1 response xml to another request XML is Property Transfer.